# How to install a python package for ipython under conda

Tags: python, conda

I'm a beginner with python so this is probably an easy fix.  I have both python and ipython on my system.  I need to use a package called ner found here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ner/  I have successfully installed it using 'python setup.py install' so that it works when I open the python shell using 'python' command.

However I also have and use ipython on my system.  I installed this a long time ago, using conda.  When I start ipython and try to 'import ner' it can't find it, because I believe ipython/conda puts its packages somewhere else.  So I don't understand how to install ner for use by ipython.  Thanks.

Comment: what os are you using? If unix show the output of `which python` and `which ipython`

Comment: OS X.  
$ which python
/Users/david/miniconda3/bin/python     
$ which ipython
//anaconda/bin/ipython

Answer (score 1):

Using the commands:

```
conda skeleton pypi ner
conda build ner
```

I created a ner conda package and uploaded it to binstar.org under my user name.

You can install it with:

```
conda install -c travis ner
```

You could also try to make sure pip is installed into your conda environment:

```
conda install pip
```

and then install ner into each environment separately using pip:

```
pip install ner
```

Comment: how does `pip install ner` know which environment to place `ner` into?

Comment: @Roland pip will install to whatever env it is installed to. So if you are using pip in outside a virtualenv, it will install ner to conda's default python installation. If you are using pip in a virtualenv, it will install ner to that virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon @travis-oliphant's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25149623/1193874). If you have built the package as described by doing:

```
conda skeleton pypi ner
conda build ner
```

Then you can now install that, locally built package, in any of your other environments by doing `conda install --use-local ner`.  This can be generalized for handling other packages which you can find on pypi but for which you can't find the conda package version.